# Do rest parameters allow for optimization?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[The Managing `arguments` section in Bluebird's article on Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments) states that:

> The `arguments` object must not be passed or leaked anywhere.

In other words, don't do the following:

```
function leaky(){
    return arguments;
}
```

But do do this:

```
function not_leaky(){
    var i = arguments.length,
        args = [];
    while(i--) args[i] = arguments[i];
    return args;
}
```

With the introduction of [Rest paramters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), will passing the rest parameter array still cause optimization issues?  From what I am understanding, the issue is that we can't let the actual `arguments` Object get loose.  Finite, defined copies of `arguments` are OK, but not the actual Object itself.  If that is the case, is the rest argument treated as an OK and optimizable copy of `arguments` when used in the following way?

```
function maybe_optimizable(...args){
    return args;
}
```

---

Specifically, I'm trying to write a `debounce` function based on [David Walsh's `debounce` function (which is based on Underscore.js')](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) and I believe there is an issue with assigning `arguments` to a variable within the top scope of the `debounce` function.  To rectify this I wrote the following:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;
    return function (...args) {
        let context = this,
            now = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) {
                func.apply(context, args);
            }
        }, wait);
        if (now) {
            func.apply(context, args);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: i believe so. As rest params create a simple array, i think it is optimizable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the challenges with the `arguments` object, is that it needs to be a *live* collection of the parameters values, *even when they are reassigned*. See how even a (parameter) variable with a primitive value gets changed without any explicit assignment to it, and it happens outside of the function:

```js
function modify(arr) {
    arr[0] = 3;
}

(function (a) {
    console.log('arguments is an ' + arguments.constructor.name);
    console.log('a is ', a);
    modify(arguments);
    console.log('after calling modify, a is ', a);
})(0);
```

See [this blog](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/) for more on such behaviour.

One can imagine that code optimisation becomes a nightmare when such an object travels around, never losing such magical capabilities.

This of course, does not happen with a normal array, and the array you get with the spread syntax is indeed a normal array:

```js
(function (...args) {
    console.log('args is an ' + args.constructor.name);
})(0);
```

You can rest (no pun intended) assured that the mentioned code optimisation problems with `arguments` do not apply to `...args`.

#### *Strict mode fixes it all*

As Bergi mentioned. The *live* semantic of `arguments` is no longer there when the function, whose `arguments` variable is used, is written in strict mode JavaScript:

```js
function modify(arr) {
    arr[0] = 3;
}

(function (a) {
    "use strict"; // <-----
    console.log('In strict mode');
    console.log('arguments is still an ' + arguments.constructor.name);
    console.log('a is ', a);
    modify(arguments);
    console.log('after calling modify, a is still ', a);
})(0);
```

As stated in [mdn's article on strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler):

> strict mode code doesn't alias properties of `arguments` objects created within it. In normal code within a function whose first argument is `arg`, setting `arg` also sets `arguments[0]`, and vice versa (unless no arguments were provided or `arguments[0]` is deleted). `arguments` objects for strict mode functions store the original arguments when the function was invoked. `arguments[i]` does not track the value of the corresponding named argument, nor does a named argument track the value in the corresponding `arguments[i]`.

Comment: Don't forget that strict mode fixes it all. It's just the weirdness of an array-like object (instead of a real array) then.

Comment: @Bergi, indeed, snippet added to illustrate that. Thanks!