# Rest syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variadic-functions

There is a rule in JS:  Never use arguments, opt to use rest syntax ... instead.
Ok, let's try. I write:

```js
let arr = [16, 'mother', 'kids'];

function concatenateAll(...arr) {
  return arr.join('');
}
```

But the output in the console doesn't satisfy the rule.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you call the function? `concatenateAll(...arr)`?

Comment: Can you post all of your code please?

Comment: Who did you think set this rule? `arguments` still works fine if you want to use it.

Comment: "*the output in the console doesn't satisfy the rule*" - you are not outputting anything to the console. And what rule would it satisfy?

Comment: @Li357, thank you !! It works !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do rest parameters allow for optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333685/do-rest-parameters-allow-for-optimization)

Comment: Kind of pointless to pass in an array then use rest.

Comment: @Bergi I think that there are "superstitions" about `arguments` by those that don't completely understand it.  I think the OP is worried the same issues that I have in my question that I proposed as a duplicate.  It would be helpful if the OP cited where they read "Never use arguments" for more context though.  As you commented in that post though, "strict mode fixes it all".

Comment: @Bergi I think OP means the preference against arguments. It doesn't have Array prototypal methods, and can clash with names right?

Comment: @Li357 Not saying that rest parameters are easier to use, but I don't see any merit in "never use arguments".

Answer (score 1):

You did not call the function seems to be your problem.

```js
let arr = [16, 'mother', 'kids'];

function concatenateAll(...arr) {
  return arr.join('');
}

console.log('Passing 3 individual arguments to the function returns: ', concatenateAll(...arr));
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing.